# ThreadPool or BackgroundWorker for high-priority download?

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7

I have list of items. Each of them has an image, which is downloaded via ThreadPool.
User can press on the item, so item's detailed image should be downloaded as soon as possible.

For now, detailed image is also downloaded via ThreadPool, which makes large delay (it waits, until rest of list images would be downloaded). So, i see several ways:

1. When user is moving to item details page, clean ThreadPool from all previous tasks and add task to download item's detail image.
2. Just freeze ThreadPool, wait until item's detail image would be downloaded (not using ThreadPool), unfreeze ThreadPool.
3. Add to ThreadPool a new task with really high priority (not sure that it is possible).
4. Use BackgroundWorker and hope that item's detail image would be downloaded quite fast.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download this image ASAP, you really need to stop all other downloads. The bottleneck, more than likely, is the network bandwidth. Hence, you want all other downloads to stop taking any more bandwidth so that your detailed image can load ASAP.

Thus, I would choose 1. The other choices don't stop downloads that are already in progress.

Comment: But how can i do that? ThreadPool doesnt have anything like "Wait", or "Freeze".. i guess, tasks in ThreadPool are like "FireAndForget", without any control.. espeshially web requests

Comment: Tasks can be cancelled. (You'll have to implement the cancellation.) Most requests do have an option to cancel, e.g. WebClient has CancelAsync().

Comment: Any samples? I didnt get the idea.. afaik, i cant just run through tasks like foreach(var task in ThreadPool.GetTasks()) { task.Stop(); }

Comment: No, you can't run through them like that. Let's say you are using WebClient to download. In your threads, save the WebClients somewhere so that you can iterate through them and CancelAsync them.

Comment: Well.. i ended up with adding locker, which forbids creation of new web requests, while ImageAsap is loaded.